# Strophe js receive only one message

Tags: javascript, strophe

I use strophe js with an xmpp server.I send from strophe client a message to another client.Client receive the message.FromCLient i can send only one message to strophe client.Strophe client receive only one message.Why?Here is my code:

```
    var connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind/');

    connection.connect('marian112@localhost', 'secret', function (status)
        {
            if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED)
            {   
                console.log('Connected to server')
                //connection.jid='marian12@localhost'
                connection.addHandler(on_chat_message, null, 'message', 'chat',null,null);
                connection.send($pres().c("priority").t("10"));
                connection.addHandler(on_presence, null, 'presence');
                connection.addHandler(on_error_iq, null, 'iq', 'error');
                connection.send($pres().tree());
                console.log(connection.jid);
                var sendMessageQuery = $msg({to: 'marian@localhost/BBXFRONT', type: 'chat'}).c('body').t('AAAAAA');
                connection.send(sendMessageQuery);
            }
        });
    var on_chat_message=function(msg) {
        var sendMessageQuery = $msg({to: 'marian@localhost/BBXFRONT', type: 'chat'}).c('body').t('bbbb');
        connection.send(sendMessageQuery);
    console.log(msg);
    console.log('You have received a message!');
    var to = msg.getAttribute('to');
    var from = msg.getAttribute('from');
    var type = msg.getAttribute('type');
    console.log(to+'  '+from+'   '+type);
    var elems = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var message=Strophe.getText(body);
    console.log(message);
    return true;
}

var on_presence=function(stanza) {
    console.log(stanza);
    return true;
}

var on_error_iq=function(stanza) {
    console.log(stanza);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I had an issue with XMPP, so I have stumbled upon your piece of code. I have checked it and the problem is here

```
var elems = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');
var message=Strophe.getText(body);
```

You are defining **elems** and then getting text from **body** element, and **body** element is not defined at this point. Since **getElementsByTagName** returns an array, this chunk of code shoud be like this:

```
var body = msg.getElementsByTagName('body');
var message=Strophe.getText(body[0]);
```

I know it is not relevant anymore, but it can help someone who have problems with **XMPP/Strophe** to have a working example.

Answer (score -1):

Every thing ok but u can modify the below mention line like this 
**connection.addHandler(on_chat_message, null, 'message', null,null,null);**

its work contiue